# Swift UI navigation Stack - infinite loop

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I am loading a page inside NavigationStack as given below,

```
@State private var showLoginView = false
var body: some View {
    

NavigationStack {
        content()
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showLoginView) {
            LoginView(viewModel: LoginViewModel(pageId: "login_view"))
        }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $showRegistrationView) {
            RegistrationView(viewModel: RegistrationViewModel(pageId: "registration_view"))
        }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $continueAsGuest, destination: {
            TabbedView(viewModel: TabbedViewModel())
        })
    }
}
```

On a button click, I set the value of showLoginView as true and load the login view. The login view has options to login and has two buttons, one for forgot password and the other to register a new account.

```
var body: some View {
            content()
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showForgotPasswordView, destination: {
                    ForgotPasswordView(viewModel: ForgotPasswordViewModel(pageId: "forgot_password_view"))
                })
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showRegistrationView, destination: {
                    RegistrationView(viewModel: RegistrationViewModel(pageId: "registration_view"))
                })
    }
```

I am setting showRegistrationView as true on button click, and the value is set to true only once, but the ForgotPasswordView or RegistrationView is called infinite times and it never ends. What's the reason for this behavior?

To prevent this, I am setting the value to false like this,

```
ForgotPasswordView(viewModel: ForgotPasswordViewModel(pageId: "forgot_password_view")).onAppear {
                        self.showForgotPasswordView = false
                    }
```

This prevents infinite loading and loads the view correctly, but when I dismiss the view, the LoginView is displayed for a second and immediately an empty view is loaded, but if I click back on that empty view the initial view is displayed.

I am not sure why the destination is triggered infinite times and also when dismissed why an empty view is displayed.

Comment: It isn’t safe to initialize objects in the body of a view

Comment: I didn't get you, what do you mean?

Comment: Creating those ViewModels in the body is unsafe

Comment: not only unsafe, it creates a completely new viewModel that has no relations to any other. Have a look at this official link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is your view model already so you don't need other ones